# Null value not showing up

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-null

**1. I am having trouble for Null value not showing up I tried with Null defined as === or == and also "" and '' and also I tried using hardcode but still not showing up anything

2. this my output I am getting [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI1q1.png)
3. this is the original table
   [original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAhye.png)

here is my php code**

```
<?php

  while($record = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        if(!strcmp($record[6],"M")){
            $sex_color='blue';
            }else{
            $sex_color='red';
            }
        if(!strcmp($record[5], "NULL")){
            $sal_color='red';
            } else{
            $sal_color='black';
            $avg=$avg+(double)$record[5];
            $count=$count+1;
            }
        echo "<tr><td>{$record[0]}</td><td>{$record[1]}</td><td>{$record[2]}</td><td>{$record[3]}</td><td>{$record[4]}</td><td style=\"color:{$sex_color}\">{$record[6]}</td><td style=\"color:{$sal_color}\">{$record[5]}</td><td>{$record[7]}</td></tr>\n";
      
        
   

?>
```

Comment: use this function ```mysqli_fetch_assoc()``` instead of this ```fetch_array```

Comment: try: `$record[x]==NULL?"NULL":$record[x]`  (replace x with proper number )

Comment: for mysql_fetch_assoc(), I got this Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!strcmp($record[5], "NULL")){
```

Have you tried [removing the quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) from "NULL"?

```
        if(!strcmp($record[5], NULL)){
            $sal_color='red';
            } else{
         $record[5]="NULL"; 
            $sal_color='black';
            $avg=$avg+(double)$record[5];
            $count=$count+1;
            }
```

or you could use the [is_null()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) function possibly.

Comment: still is not working show in my an error

Comment: I did not test the code because I do not have your setup. 

To clarify - you want the null to have the word NULL in the output? Or are you just trying to control formatting on the other cells when the value is null?

Comment: want the null to have the word NULL in the output because Null is there is my original table. I am thankful for your comment and help

Comment: This may also help you: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp